# saving file on razor pages

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have a pdf file saved on a server on my wwwroot folder inside folder called 'filledpdffiles". I want to put a save button the Razor page so that when the user clicks on the save button, the file from folder "filledpdffiles" gets saved on their local computer on a particular directory. below is my directory structure:

[image]

I want the users to save "confidentiality Statement" and "Package 2022" on their local drive. This is an intranet application. How can I achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `FileStreamResult` class to read the PDF file from the server's file system and return it as a file stream to the user's browser.

for more please refer to - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.filestreamresult?view=aspnetcore-6.0